# Talend txmlmap generate Sequence for Child

Tags: talend

I am new to talend and trying to parse xml document and generate etl sequence to maintain the child parent relationship. Situation here is I have a xml like this :

```xml
<RDF>
    <footPrint>
        <custid>123</custid>
        <item>
            <itemCd>apple</itemCd>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemCd>orange</itemCd>
        </item>
    </footPrint>
    <footPrint>
        <custid>456</custid>
        <item>
            <itemCd>grapes</itemCd>
        </item>
        <item>
            <itemCd>kiwi</itemCd>
        </item>
    </footPrint>
</RDF>
```

And the output I am trying to achieve is :

```
id | Custid | item_seq | item
-------------------------------
1  | 123    | 1        | apple

1  | 123    | 2        | orange

2  | 456    | 1        | grapes

2  | 456    | 2        | kiwi
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use tFIleInputXML and set Xpath loop query to "/RDF/footPrint/item"

add two columns to schema i.e. cust_id and item. these column will automatically reflet in mapping content.

than for cust_id set Xpath query to - "../custid"
for item set Xpath query to "itemCd"

you will get your result.
hope this help...

Comment: As far as I understand item_seq is missing in your answer. Maybe use a Number generator for that?